# Duplicate text in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, countif

I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of ID's that my community uses to track how many times a player has received a "restore". Currently I have conditional formatting setup to color the cell red if there is a duplicate. I want to get a bit more in depth with it though.

1 occurrence of the ID = No color change
2 occurrences of the ID = Cell red
3+ occurrences of the ID = all the duplicates go yellow background with red text, and if possible adds text 3 cells to the right of the duplicate saying "Third restore!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data is in ColumnA, clear any CF from that column and please try selecting ColumnA and: HOME > Styles, Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., Use  a formula to determine which cells to format and **Format values where this formula is true:** of:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=2
```

with red highlighting. <kbd>OK</kbd>. Then add a second formula rule of:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>2
```

with yellow highlighting and red font.